# Replace an existing state machine in solidus

Tags: ruby-on-rails, state-machine, solidus

I need to customize few state machines' behaviour for our business requirement and followed the [documentation](https://guides.solidus.io/how-tos/how-to-replace-an-existing-state-machine) for the solidus recommended way of replacing an existing state machine. However, I am not being able to do so this way. Do I have to do something extra besides the fact mentioned in the documentation ? I can also think of an alternative way of clearing out existing states and events for the models and redefining the state machines required in the models themselves. However, I prefer to go with this way if possible.

Here, the application traceback for the issue.

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Devise::Models::Authenticatable::BLACKLIST_FOR_SERIALIZATION is deprecated! Use Devise::Models::Authenticatable::UNSAFE_ATTRIBUTES_FOR_SERIALIZATION instead. (called from <main> at /home/sis/Bajra/adguru/config/application.rb:27)
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 6.0.3.7 application starting in development 
=> Run `rails server --help` for more startup options
Exiting
Traceback (most recent call last):
    69: from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
    68: from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    67: from /home/sis/Bajra/adguru/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
    66: from /home/sis/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    65: from /home/sis/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    64: from /home/sis/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    63: from /home/sis/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    62: from /home/sis/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    61: from /home/sis/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    60: from /home/sis/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    59: from /home/sis/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    58: from /home/sis/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    57: from /home/sis/Bajra/adguru/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    56: from /home/sis/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
    55: from /home/sis/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
    54: from /home/sis/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
    53: from /home/sis/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.7/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
    52: from /home/sis/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.7/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in `perform'
    51: from /home/sis/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
    50: from /home/sis/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
    49: from /home/sis/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    48: from /home/sis/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.7/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:138:in `perform'
    47: from /home/sis/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.7/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:138:in `tap'
    46: from /home/sis/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.7/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:147:in `block in perform'
    45: from /home/sis/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.7/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:37:in `start'
    44: from /home/sis/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.7/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:77:in `log_to_stdout'
    43: from /home/sis/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:422:in `wrapped_app'
    42: from /home/sis/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:249:in `app'
    41: from /home/sis/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:349:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    40: from /home/sis/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:66:in `parse_file'
    39: from /home/sis/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:105:in `load_file'
    38: from /home/sis/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `new_from_string'
    37: from /home/sis/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `eval'
    36: from config.ru:5:in `block in <main>'
    35: from config.ru:5:in `require_relative'
    34: from /home/sis/Bajra/adguru/config/environment.rb:7:in `<main>'
    33: from /home/sis/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.7/lib/rails/application.rb:363:in `initialize!'
    32: from /home/sis/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
    31: from /home/sis/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    30: from /home/sis/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
    29: from /home/sis/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    28: from /home/sis/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
    27: from /home/sis/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
    26: from /home/sis/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    25: from /home/sis/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:415:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    24: from /home/sis/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:415:in `call'
    23: from /home/sis/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `tsort_each_child'
    22: from /home/sis/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `each'
    21: from /home/sis/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:421:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    20: from /home/sis/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    19: from /home/sis/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:422:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    18: from /home/sis/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    17: from /home/sis/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
    16: from /home/sis/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
    15: from /home/sis/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
    14: from /home/sis/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
    13: from /home/sis/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.7/lib/rails/engine.rb:624:in `block in <class:Engine>'
    12: from /home/sis/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.7/lib/rails/engine.rb:624:in `each'
    11: from /home/sis/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.7/lib/rails/engine.rb:625:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
    10: from /home/sis/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.7/lib/rails/engine.rb:665:in `load_config_initializer'
     9: from /home/sis/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.7/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:182:in `instrument'
     8: from /home/sis/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.7/lib/rails/engine.rb:666:in `block in load_config_initializer'
     7: from /home/sis/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:318:in `load'
     6: from /home/sis/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
     5: from /home/sis/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:318:in `block in load'
     4: from /home/sis/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:39:in `load'
     3: from /home/sis/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:39:in `load'
     2: from /home/sis/Bajra/adguru/config/initializers/spree.rb:6:in `<main>'
     1: from /home/sis/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/solidus_core-2.10.0.beta1/lib/spree/core.rb:45:in `config'
/home/sis/Bajra/adguru/config/initializers/spree.rb:22:in `block in <main>': undefined method `state_machines' for #<Spree::AppConfiguration:0x000055cc946bb3c0> (NoMethodError)
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using an old version of Solidus. The feature described in the guides you linked, which allows using a different class for your state machines, refers to more recent versions (`2.11+` if I recall correctly).

If you want you can still customize your state machines by monkey patching them. For example, to change the Order state machine:

```
# app/overrides/your_store/order/do_stuff_after_confirm.rb

module YourStore
  module Order
    module DoStuffAfterConfirm
      def self.prepended(base)
        base.state_machine.after_transition to: :confirm, do: :your_business!
      end

      def your_business!
        # ...
      end

      Spree::Order.prepend self
    end
  end
end
```